# What am I doing wrong? Please correct my code

Tags: sql

Question 1: **In the PRODUCT table, change P_INDATE to (January 18, 2014), the P_PRICE to 17.99 and the P_MIN to 10 for the product 13-Q2/P2.**

I'm a beginner so I need some clarification. Here is my code:

```
UPDATE PRODUCT
SET P_INDATE = '2014-JAN-18 05:03:12'
SET P_PRICE = '17.99'
SET P_MIN = '10'
WHERE P_CODE = 13-Q2/P2;
```

Question 2: 3.  **Delete all rows from the product table for which the P_MIN is equal to 5.**

Note: I keep getting an error saying that a child record has been found. In the product table, there is a foreign key (V_CODE) from the vendor table.

```
DELETE FROM PRODUCT
WHERE EXISTS
 (SELECT *
FROM VENDOR
WHERE VENDOR.V_CODE = PRODUCT.V_CODE
AND P_MIN = 05);
```

Any help would be great. Been stuck on these for a few days...

Comment: Your numerical values should *not* be 'quoted', however your `p_code` should be `= '13-Q2/P2' `

Comment: @Stu I removed the single quotes from the numeric values (17.99, 10), and added them to the P_CODE '13-Q2/P2'   . However, I'm getting an error "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"  Is there something else I need to correct?

Comment: Yes, I would review the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj26498.html) for the `update` syntax.